# Golang multiline regex not working

Tags: regex, go

Why the the following multiline regex do not work, I expect to match the substring inside the  tags. Other simples multiline matches worked correctly.

```
func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)<think>(.*)</think>`)
    const s = `That is 
    <think>
    FOOBAR
    </think>`
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", r.FindStringSubmatch(s))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/8C6u_0ca8w

Comment: Try `(?m)<think>([^<]+)</think>` or if non-greediness is supported `(?m)<think>(.*?)</think>`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8068625

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, "." doesn't match newline. If you give the "s" flag, it does. I don't think you need "m".

Note that if there are multiple `<think>...</think>` in your string, the regexp will match everything between the first `<think>` and the last `</think>`. Using `.*?` will cause it to only match the contents of the first one.

Comment: I thought the same thing about `.` but in golang `s` is set by default: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax Although this does seem to fix it so I guess the docs are wrong...

Comment: If `s=true`, then the new line will match, the default is `false`. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 12):

Do not use regexp to parse XML, instead use [encoding/xml](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/). Example of a corner-case which is impossible to handle in regexp: `<think><elem attrib="I'm pondering about </think> tag now"></elem></think>`

I'll use `START` and `STOP` as markers, just to disassociate from any XML stuff. Complete example (includes both LF and CRLF line endings, just in case) with a [link to The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bKPUo9p3Tp9):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)START(.*?)STOP`)
    const s = "That is \nSTART\nFOOBAR\r\n\r\nSTOP\n"
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", r.FindStringSubmatch(s))
}
```

returns:

```
[]string{"START\nFOOBAR\r\n\r\nSTOP", "\nFOOBAR\r\n\r\n"}
```

Comment: As previous answers have mentioned and assuming OP wants to match matching XML tags - if there's another `</think>` tag then a greedy match will include everything in between. Use a non-greedy pattern `(.*?)` with FindAllStringSubmatch to get all matches.
Edit: Playground [link](https://play.golang.org/p/TWElZ2jGsRr)

Comment: @shaktisinghr Yeah, no. I've updated my answer to disassociate it completely from the idea of parsing XML using regexp. Now it's just about a generic non-greedy multiline regexp. Thanks for your comment.